# Running emacs remotely fails when no X11 forwarding

Tags: java, linux, emacs

I have been writing java program that I start from the terminal. One of the tasks my program must perform is to open a text file in my favorite text editor. I have accomplished this fairly easily with the following command, but it only works in certain scenarios.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("emacs "+p.fullName);
```

This works great when I am on my local Linux, and when I ssh in to a computer using the -X flag (for X11). At these times, the editor pops up in a separate window. However, if I ssh without -X, my beloved text editor never appears. It is the times that I am trying to open the editor in the same terminal as the Java program.

The reason for this seems to make sense, the java program is currently occupying the terminal, so the editor either gets created in a detached state or not at all.  Either way, what I'd like to do is somehow put my program in the background and set up my editor as my foreground process. And is there a better term for this than context switching?

Edit: Emacs gives me this error at the moment: **emacs: standard input is not a tty**

Edit: Removed mentions of Lanterna, because bug is reproducible without it.

Comment: Does emacs output any error messages? If you run emacs with the `-nw`   option, does that start emacs successfully?

Comment: After much finagling, I finally got an error msg out of emacs: emacs: standard input is not a tty

Comment: Try giving ssh the `-t` or `-tt ` option to force the remote side to allocate a tty.